# How to circumscribe a cilinder around an irregular shape using edges of irregular shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

[image]

How can I create a cylinder using these edges shown in the picture?

Is there an easy way or any tutorial?

Cylinder not with only 7 faces, round shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding a new cylinder with more sides in this case.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add a new object, and select *Mesh* > *Cylinder.*

Before you click or do anything else, you should see a small collapsed box in the bottom left corner labelled *Add Cylinder*. Expand it, and change the number of vertices (first option).

If you're looking for a good beginner tutorial series, I would recommend you follow the [Donut Tutorial Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U) by BlenderGuru.

**Edit:**

Here's a lengthier method if you want to build off the starting mesh.

If you want to keep the original shape, first duplicate it then work off of the new object.

With the object selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode. Press <kbd>2</kbd> to enter edge select mode, and while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, click on one of the horizontal edges on the top, and bottom. This should have selected the top/bottom edge loops.

[image: Selected loops]

Now, right-click (or left, if you're using right-click select), and select *Subdivide* at the top of the menu that pops up. This will add additional vertical cuts in the middle of all the faces.

Now, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and select one of the original vertical edges. This should select all the vertical edges. Next, go to the *Select* drop-down menu in the top left corner, and select *Checker Deselect.* Now only the newly added edges should be selected.

Now, you can press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale in XY axes only. Scale it up a bit, and there you go, the mesh is closer to a cylinder. If you want a clearer view of the mesh while scaling, press <kbd>7</kbd> on the Numpad to enter the top orthographic view.

If you wish to add even more sides, you can repeat this process.

If you're looking for a smoothly shaded cylinder, follow the process below.

In edit mode, select the top and bottom edge loops using the same shortcut as before, then right-click and select *Mark Seam.* Then, <kbd>Tab</kbd> back out into object mode, right-click and select *Shade Smooth.*

The last thing you will need to do is to go to the *Object Properties* tab (the icon is a green triangle with squares on each corner), and go to *Normals* > *Auto-smooth.* Enable auto-smooth.

This is the result using one iteration of subdividing the surface.

[image: Final result]

Comment: thank you #stphnl329 for your quick reply.

You are right, in this example the first option is adding a new cilinder using the center of this example, but in other examples you only have some edges. 

You must think that probably both object centers are different.

I need a cilinder exactly fitted to those edges (at least 3) not "approximately" fitted.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll go through a bit lengthier process in detail if you want to build off the original source mesh.

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you for your reply. I think my example wasn't good, I was talking about the vertical edges to look for that reference, but the original shape is similar to a star and top and bottom surfaces are not like this example.

So I'm sorry again, but think in a big shape so you cannot use the top or bottom area, and the only references are those edges I pointed in the picture.

I'm thinking in Add > Circle and then using Snap tool, but I don't know how to snap only 3 vertices of the circle to the edges without loosing the perfect circle-shape.

Comment: I'm not sure of any method that you can use to automatically center and resize the circle to fit all the points. I would probably eyeball it or modify the other object, but it all really depends on what your end goal is.

Comment: thank you all. I finally adjust the adges of the original shape to the external cilynder using the snap. Snap-Edges center and left-clic + Ctrl.